# getAll values from Doctrine entity (Symfony3)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this controller:

```
public function getLogAction()
    {
        $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(ChangeLog::class)->findAll();
        if ($result === NULL) {
            return new View("Log not found", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return new View($result,Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

and this Entity.ChangeLog.yml:

```
AppBundle\Entity\ChangeLog:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            type: integer
        date:
            access_type: public_method
            expose: true
            type: datetime
        user:
            type: AppBundle\Entity\Category
            access_type: public_method
            expose: true
            type: string
        entityName:
            expose: true
            type: string
        entityId:
            type: int
            expose: true
        action:
            type: string
            expose: true
        changeSet:
            type: array
            expose: true
        description:
            type: string
            expose: true
```

When I try to get all records in table, I receive this error, but I can't understand what is wrong in my metadata:

> Expected metadata for class AppBundle\Entity\ChangeLog to be defined
>   in
>   /vagrant/catalog/app/config/serializer/AppBundle/Entity.ChangeLog.yml

I DB my records look like this:
[image]

I think, that I need to do something with change_set, but I have no idea how to do that... Maybe you can help me...
**Update1**

After some manipulation with metadata (edit) I receive this error:

> Warning: ReflectionProperty::getValue() expects parameter 1 to be
>   object, string given

Comment: you should move the configuration for serialization in a different files (as the error suggested). PS: The `findAll` method return a doctrine collection so in case of no data was found it will return an empty collection (not a null values). Is better you change with `if (count($result) == 0) {`  Hope this help

Comment: @Matteo thanks, i did some refactor in my Entity.ChaneLog.yml (edit in question) and now I get warning, that I described above. I thing this error appears because tables are linked.

Comment: The first error is showing a file path and namespace error you should check the namspace and directory structure. Second error is because when ever you will insert an entity in database by serializing and try to d-seriarlize it's will throw this error. To prevent this you need to understand by this https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/pull/290#issuecomment-159778071

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this error

```
Warning: ReflectionProperty::getValue() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given
```

is because you have two type

```
user:
    type: AppBundle\Entity\Category
    access_type: public_method
    expose: true
    type: string
```